# A fair 6-sided dice is rolled repeatedly. What is the expected number of throws to observe three distinct numbers for the first time?

Tags: probability

Here, the faces are numbered 1,2,3,4,5,6 and the throws are assumed to be independent of each other.
If we try working backwards from the throw, lets say $ r^{th}$ throw, in which we observed the third distinct number we can find the probability of $X = r$, where X is the number of throws to get three distinct numbers for the first time. The first $r-1$ throws have all the possible combinations any selected 2 distinct numbers and then the $r^{th}$ throw should get any of the rest 4 numbers.

$$P(X=r) = \dbinom{6}{2}. \left\{\dbinom{r-1}{1}.\left(\cfrac {1}{6}\right)^{1}.\left(\cfrac {1}{6}\right)^{r-2}+ \dbinom{r-1}{2}.\left(\cfrac {1}{6}\right)^{2}.\left(\cfrac {1}{6}\right)^{r-3}+....+ \dbinom{r-1}{r-2}.\left(\cfrac {1}{6}\right)^{r-2}.\left(\cfrac {1}{6}\right)^{1}\right\}.\cfrac{4}{6} $$
However, it is getting messier to calculate $E(X)$ from the above $P(X=r)$. Is it even correct and how to proceed further?

Comment: Following from the typical approach to solving the coupon-collector's problem but stopping the sum early... 1 to get the first,  $\frac{6}{5}$ to get the second, $\frac{6}{4}$ to get the third, adding up this gives $1+\frac{6}{5}+\frac{6}{4}=3.7$